# Disable health-check logging in AWS ELB Django Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, elastic-beanstalk, mod-wsgi

I have a Django application running on aws-elastic-beanstalk. I try to disable the logs caused by my health-checks. The health-checks are already routed to a seperate page.

Elastic-beanstalk uses Apache + mod_wsgi.

Here is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32921021/9177173) that works with nginx servers. I try to create something similar for apache.

I found out that [conditional Logs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#conditional) are probably the appropriate way to do it with an Apache Server.

My directory struture looks like the following

```
/etc/httpd/
  - conf 
      - httpd.conf # main conf
  - conf.d 
      - wsgi.conf # virtual hosts
      - additional config files
```

my attempt:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/disable_health_logs.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        <IfModule mod_setenvif>
            SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/health/$" dontlog
            CustomLog logs/access_log combined env=!dontlog
        </IfModule>
```

The additional config `disable_health_logs.conf` is created but it has no effect. Neither do I see error logs nor a change in the access logs.

In the `httpd.conf` there is already the following setting:

```
 CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
```

Do I need to override it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are loading the module somewhere with the following

```
LoadModule setenvif_module <your_apache_modules_path>/mod_setenvif.so
```

Also, need to correct your IfModule as shown below (note: the .c at end)

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/health/$" dontlog
  CustomLog logs/access_log combined env=!dontlog
</IfModule>
```

What you have looks correct otherwise.

Comment: `apachectl -M` yields among others: `setenvif_module` so it is loaded per default

Comment: also the `.c` ending does not change anything... the logs are still appearing

Comment: I solved it myself by outcommenting manually in the httpd.conf you were right with the .c however it was not the reason for why it didn't work

Comment: Where is "logs/access_log"? Wouldn't it be "/var/log/httpd/access_log" if on apache for example?

Answer (score 0):

So I had another go on this.

The problem really is the setting in the `httpd.conf`. If I outcomment the line:

```
#CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
```

manually via ssh my settings are used and the health-checks disappear from the logs.

Note that this is not really a permanent solution as beanstalk might spin up a new instance and override the httpd.conf again